# tesseract identifying the whole image as single box?

Tags: tesseract

I am trying to train the tesseract 3.02 on Ubuntu 14.04.  I followed the guidelines mentioned on [Cedric's blog](http://blog.cedric.ws/how-to-train-tesseract-301).

First I tried to generate a box file using the following command:

```
tesseract eng.mr.exp0.jpg eng.mr.exp0 batch.nochop makebox
```

But the above command is generating a box file with a single line with the whole image as a single box (actually it should have generated a box file with 6 lines).  So, I used jTessBoxEditor to edit the box file and create 6 boxes with appropriate co-ordinates and characters).  Now when I try to train the tesseract with the above created box file using the command

```
tesseract eng.mr.exp0.jpg eng.mr.exp0.box nobatch box.train
```

I get the error:

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.03 with Leptonica
FAIL!
APPLY_BOXES: boxfile line 1/0 ((20,24),(95,192)): FAILURE! Couldn't find a matching blob
FAIL!
APPLY_BOXES: boxfile line 2/7 ((96,24),(171,192)): FAILURE! Couldn't find a matching blob
FAIL!
APPLY_BOXES: boxfile line 3/0 ((172,24),(248,192)): FAILURE! Couldn't find a matching blob
FAIL!
APPLY_BOXES: boxfile line 4/3 ((248,24),(324,192)): FAILURE! Couldn't find a matching blob
FAIL!
APPLY_BOXES: boxfile line 5/3 ((324,24),(400,192)): FAILURE! Couldn't find a matching blob
FAIL!
APPLY_BOXES: boxfile line 6/0 ((400,24),(476,192)): FAILURE! Couldn't find a matching blob
APPLY_BOXES:
   Boxes read from boxfile:       6
   Boxes failed resegmentation:       6
APPLY_BOXES: Unlabelled word at :Bounding box=(0,19)->(480,192)
   Found 0 good blobs.
   1 remaining unlabelled words deleted.
Generated training data for 0 words
```

What is the mistake I am making?

Image used is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9m83smx3VkAYmtFOVc2Q0tYVG8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi..Same error i got in my mac system. Please post answer if you get it now. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That image is so dirty! You will need to clean it up first before any OCR software can recognize, or train with, it. Once the image preprocessed, you can use `mirc.traineddata` found in this Tesseract forum [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/obWI4cz8rXg).